# What is "at the very heart of need"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How to understand?:

1. Water strikes at the very heart of need.
2. Meaning of "need" in 1st question.
3. salty kind... kind of water or what?

Speaking ahead of the trip Mr Smith said: “Water strikes at the very heart of need. To voyage almost 3,000 miles upon the salty kind will make us intensely aware of places in the world that are without adequate supplies.”

Comment: It just means that *fresh* water is essential, a fact you'll realize if you take a trip over 3,000 miles of salt water (which of course you can't drink).

Comment: Why do you comment and don‘t post the answer. I understand exacrly the same.

Comment: Because the question is too trivial for an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. The heart is the center of the body - and the most important organ - is standing for the *center*. It will say: The central, capital, main need is the water.
2. The salty kind is the water of the sea or salt lake.